# How to create a list of all innerHTMLs of all the XPATH elements

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Using `selenium`, How can we fetch a list of innerHTMLs of a same XPATH element?

What is the scenario :-

Relevant HTML :

```
<span class="AbcD">2017 Year</span>
<span class="AbcD">2015 Year</span>
<span class="AbcD">2011 Year</span>
<span class="AbcD">2012 Year</span>
<span class="AbcD">2018 Year</span>
```

What is the expected :-

What i am known is `<span class="AbcD">` element is there for many times.
And i want innerHTMLs of all the `spans` in a `ArrayList` like :

```
{2017 Year, 2015 Year, 2011 Year, 2012 Year, 2018 Year}
```

What i have tried :-

JAVA :

```
List<String> PreviousList= new ArrayList<>();
PreviousList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='AbcD']")).innerHTML;
```

Comment: U r calling an innerhtml() method on a list, wont work. Iterate the list and call gettext() etc on each webelement. If on java 8 use streams for an easier solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code from Java 8 :

```
List<String> yearList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='AbcD']")).stream().map(element -> element.getAttribute("innerText")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Hope that helps you.

In simple terms :

```
List<WebElement> years = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='AbcD']"));
List<String> yearsList = new ArrayList<>();
for(WebElement year : years) {
    yearsList.add(year.getAttribute("innerText"));
}
System.out.println(yearsList);
```

Both will work.

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have provided to collect all the *innerHTMLs* of all the `<span>` tags in an ArrayList you can use the following solution:

```
List<String> textList= new ArrayList<>();
List<WebElement> PreviousList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='AbcD']"));
for (WebElement ele:PreviousList)
    textList.add(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try JS method:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='AbcD']"));
    List<String> previousList= new ArrayList<>();
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        previousList.add((String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element));
    }

//or using JAVA 8 features:
    List<String> previousList = elements.stream()
            .map(webElement -> (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", webElement))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```